# Liquid: If sum (plus) greater than

Tags: liquid

Why is this operation in LIQUID not working correctly?

```
{% if beschr[0].size | plus: beschr[1].size > 160 %}
  <script>var testval= '{{ beschr[0].size }}'; 
  alert(testval);</script>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

`beschr[0]` is 110 and `beschr[1]` is 200. This is working I'm sure, I put these values in javascript and checked. The problem, if I change "`<`" to "`>`" it's also true!! In both cases I get the alert?
Even if I write

```
{% if 100 | plus: 200 < 160 %}
```

it's true. So what I need to do is

```
{% assign summe = beschr[0].size | plus: beschr[1].size %}
{% if summe < 160 %}
```

Then it's working. But why? Did I use invalid liquid syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The liquid filters cannot be used within conditional statements. You will have to assign the variable before hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the logical || operator instead and check if it works.

```
 {% if beschr[0].size || plus: beschr[1].size > 160 %}
 <script>var testval= '{{ beschr[0].size }}'; 
      alert(testval);</script>
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working as well, but thank you for your response